# FirePHP equivelant for Ruby on Rails

Tags: php, ruby-on-rails, debugging, firebug, firephp

is there an FirePHP equivalent for Ruby On Rails?

I would like to be able to send the value of a variable to a console and browse object properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is example of what you need: http://fuelyourcoding.com/set-rails-logging-on-fire/ . There is project on Github - https://github.com/simonjefford/rack_firebug_logger, but it is rather outdated (last commit in November 2009).